# Footer won't budge

Tags: css, footer

[image]

see the example..the footer won't stay at bottom/

[image]

**EDIT**
Tried to remove clearfix but it is not pushing the footer to the bottom or eliminates the white gap below the footer. Clearfix: display block is done via the Pinnaclecart itself. 
Even if I tried to remove display:block, the footer will be in mess. For an example, it will move footer items to the left outside of the page where the products are laid out.

any insight will be appreciated!

Comment: Ehm... what? You might wanna add some more words? **edit** Or a link to a live example. That would be perfect

Comment: Where is your footer? I see a picture of some code, but need real code on a real website!

Comment: If Kyle needs it, give it to him! Give it to him fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to add the following to your #footer section in the css file:

```
position:fixed; 
bottom:100px; /* 100 being the assumed footer height, you'll need to do the math :) */
```

(also, it'd be kind to spend a little more time on your problem description)

Comment: thank you for help I will try to describe the problem. thanks. will check your css to see if it works

Comment: @My Head Hurts, it doesn't work as expected unfortunately. I think display:block is set because of two images overlapping on the footer area. Someone else did that addition, but I need to fix the white gap - so any more idea?

Comment: well, people were asking to post the code... without further information I'd suggest to save the page as a plain HTML page and try removing each style class one by one, until it works. then you know which style commands are conflicting, and it should be easy enough from there.